# Image Classification with Support Vector Machine

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I worked with Support Vector Machine for classification with skicit-learn library several time previously. But I only interacted with data contain text and number in ".csv" format. Currently, I am wanting to use Support Vector Machine for image classification. Can you help me how to convert image to type like ".csv" format in order to classification.
I would be very appreciated with any help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad - please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, in general, one would define a so-called *Feature Vector*. It's a vector which contains numeric representations of certain, usually hand-crafted features. In the case of image classification this heavily depends on what you want to classify. Usually, the features in image classification systems are extracted by image processing algorithms such as [HOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) and [SIFT](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform).

But honestly, I wouldn't use SVMs in image classification task because it's usually a lot of work to define and combine features to get a good classifier. Try [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) instead. Those learn the necessary feature by them selfs. If you spend months of feature engineering for a good SVM classifier, a CNN could easily outperform your work after the first training.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I recently tried HOG combine with SVM. Actually I train my model with CNN before, and I want to compare result with CNN. CNN gave me a much better result. I am very appreciate for you support.

Comment: You’re welcome:) just accepting my answer is enough, though:)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to implement SVM for image classification.

1. Extract hand crafted features like SIFT,HOG or similar for each image and store them in csv. Finally, apply svm over them.
2. Use deep learning, extract features before soft max classifier. Store those features in .csv and apply svm over it.